# laravel foreach loop with 2k and get relation from 200k tack long long time

Tags: php, laravel, loops

i have this model called Product
and i have model called Note_voucher_line

and this is relation inside product

```
public function get_note_voucher_lines()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Note_voucher_line','product_id','id')->orderBy('date','asc')->orderBy('note_voucher_id','asc');
}
```

now sometimes i have to loop products like this code

```
$products = Product::whereBetween('id',[$num1,$num2])->get();
foreach($products as $product)
{
    $lines = $product['get_note_voucher_lines'];
    // when i use this relation it tack long long time
}
```

the model `Note_voucher_line` has over than 300k rows
and i have index on the `migration`
and this is the index migration inside `note_voucher_lines`

```
Schema::table('note_voucher_lines', function($table) {
    $table->foreign('note_voucher_id')->references('id')->on('note_vouchers');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->foreign('journal_entry_id')->references('id')->on('journal_entries');
    $table->foreign('warehouse_id')->references('id')->on('warehouses');
    $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
    $table->foreign('cost_center_id')->references('id')->on('cost_centers');
    $table->foreign('unit_id')->references('id')->on('units');
    $table->foreign('is_it_bonus')->references('id')->on('status');
    $table->foreign('note_voucher_type_id')->references('id')->on('note_voucher_types');
    $table->foreign('posting_state_id')->references('id')->on('posting_status');
    $table->foreign('product_total_quantity_id')->references('id')->on('product_total_quantitys');
    $table->foreign('is_componentable')->references('id')->on('status');
    $table->foreign('approved_state_id')->references('id')->on('approval_status');
    $table->foreign('currency_id')->references('id')->on('currencies');
    $table->foreign('branch_id')->references('id')->on('branches');
    $table->foreign('created_by')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->foreign('deleted_by')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

there is index called product_id belong to products table
any help here to make it faster
thanks

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Sounds like you should find any other way to gather this data, probably by a raw database query that doesn't use Eloquent?

Comment: So there is place to do code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Also what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary reason for the delay seems to be the lazy loading of the get_note_voucher_lines relationship.

Every time you access this relationship inside the loop, Laravel is making a separate query to fetch the related lines. This is known as the N+1 problem.

To mitigate this, use eager loading:

```
$products = Product::whereBetween('id',[$num1,$num2])->with('get_note_voucher_lines')->get();
```

Also you can use chunking to process large data:

```
Product::whereBetween('id',[$num1,$num2])->with('get_note_voucher_lines')->chunk(100, function ($products) {
foreach ($products as $product) {

     $lines = $product->get_note_voucher_lines;
}});
```

Make sure there's an index on the id field. You mentioned there's an index, but ensure it's a proper index and not just a foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 2):

Eager-loading your relationship can be helpful in this case.

```
$products = Product::whereBetween('id',[$num1,$num2])->with('get_note_voucher_lines')->get();
foreach($products as $product)
{
    $lines = $product->get_note_voucher_lines;
    // This should be faster and note that this is the right way to fetch laravel relation not as an array
}
```

What happens here is that we used the `with()` method to preload 2k rows from the `note_voucher_lines` table (assuming your products table contains 2k rows) in each iteration as opposed to one row that gets loaded previously. This reduces the number of network calls made to the database server so that instead of making 300k calls, it now makes 300k/2k calls.

Note: you should also consider using chunk loading for your products to avoid hitting memory limits as your data continues to grow.
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#chunking-results

Comment: i already did this but the server sometimes also gone

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to process all 300k+ rows of note_voucher_lines at once, consider implementing pagination in your code. This way, you can fetch and process a limited number of records at a time, which can greatly improve performance.

```
$perPage = 50; // Adjust the number of records per page as needed
$products = Product::whereBetween('id', [$num1, $num2])->get();

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $lines = $product->get_note_voucher_lines()->paginate($perPage);
    
    // Process the lines for this product
}
```

Ensure that your database server is properly tuned for performance. This includes setting appropriate memory and buffer sizes, optimizing queries, and regularly maintaining your database (e.g., cleaning up unused data, rebuilding indexes).

If the data doesn't change frequently, consider implementing caching mechanisms to store the results of expensive queries temporarily. This can significantly reduce the load on your database.

Answer (score 1):

like Alika Matthew have said you need to use the eager loading to avoid executing extra queries for each product to get it's voucher , also you can use chunk if your server is running out of ram for processing large data

```
Product::whereBetween('id',[$num1,$num2])->with('get_note_voucher_lines')->chunk(100, function ($products) {
    foreach ($products as $product) {
 
         $lines = $product->get_note_voucher_lines;
    }
});
```